# Identifying nilpotent $2\times 2$ matrices with a quadratic cone

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, nilpotence

Recall that $A \in  \operatorname{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R})$ is called nilpotent if there exists n > 0 such that $A^n = 0.$
Observe that if A is nilpotent then its characteristic polynomial is, up to a sign,$p(λ) = λ^n$ .After identifying $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^3 $
 as vector spaces, show that the set
of nilpotent matrices in  $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is quadratic cone in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ described by the equation $x^2 +yz = 0$

I'm kind of lost in question and I just have to finish my work.
What would be the set $ Mat (2, \mathbb{R} $) and the main space icon $ \mathbb {R}^3 $, the principal, which equation $ x ^ 2 + yz = 0 $ has a To see it all, if anyone can help, I'll be very grateful.

.

Comment: A $2\times2$ matrix is nilpotent iff both its trace and its determinant are zero.

Comment: If the special linear group is the set of square matrix with determinant $1$ and a nilpotent matrix need to have null determinant... I don't understand maybe.

Comment: @RafaelGonzalezLopez $\mathfrak{sl}$ is the Lie Algebra associated with the group $SL$.  In particular, $\mathfrak{sl}$ (for the purposes of this problem) is the vector space consisting of all trace-zero matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you!